# Why just sound is played for some mp4 files?

Tags: asp.net, jwplayer, flash

I have some mp4 files that just sound is played not video with `jw player` and `f4 player`. But all other mp4 files are playing correctly.
what can be wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pump the video through Handbrake with the default options, plus check "Web optimized." I'll wager that it plays just fine in JW Player after that.

It's a freebie: http://handbrake.fr/

Answer (score 2):

MP4, like any other format, requires specific CODECs for playback.  No matter what player you are using, if you do not have the required CODEC for THAT specific clip, you will not play it back correctly.  To make matters worse, audio and video are seperate CODECs.
This is why you may hear audio, but see no video.  It's also why some clips play, and others don't.  Different CODECs.

A CODEC is a "COder/DECocer" for audio and video streams.  Unless you can view the properties of a particular clip, you really don't know what CODEC the author used.

Comment: What can I do? windows media player is playing it well. I have just problem with flash player.

Comment: Search around for CODEC packs for your player.  Evidently, it is not pulling from the same resources that Media Player is pulling from.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to encode your videos in H264.

Comment: Presumably, he already has the clips encoded.  If he can't decode them, he can't reencode them to something else.  Just saying.  But that CODEC is a fine suggestion, assuming he has that option.

Comment: There are no codec packs for the JW Player. It isn't a a desktop application, it is a tool for webmasters who wish to embed videos into their own websites.